# What's the best way to prove this?

Tags: calculus

I just started studying math and am pretty new to the "proving" since (in highschool) we did "solving" most of the time.

How to mathematically prove $$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ...} \leqslant a + b + c + ...$$  $$\forall a, b, c,... \geqslant 0$$

The only thing that comes to my mind is proving it for $$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \leqslant a + b$$ and saying that it works for the above case as well, but that just doesn't seem like the proper way if it's even correct.

Comment: Since both sides are non-negative, you are allowed to square both sides. Then, the proof is no more difficult.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: So if I prove that it works for two elements (a and b), I can say that it's going work for all other cases with more than two elements (a, b, c and so on)? Is it enough or there is a mathematical way to express that?

Comment: You have to justify that a claim is true for $n+1$ whenever it is true for $n$. This is the idea of induction. In general, we cannot conclude it. The odd numbers $3,5,7$ are prime, are all odd numbers greater than $1$ prime then ? Of course not, already the next, $9$ , is not prime.

Comment: Your idea of $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \leqslant a + b$ can be expanded by induction to a proof for any number of terms. 

For example to get from two terms to three terms you could use $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 +c^2} = \sqrt{\left(\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\right)^2 +c^2} \leqslant \sqrt{\left(a+b\right)^2 +c^2} \leqslant (a+b)+c = a+b+c$

Comment: @MarinKovač, no you can't do that; there are inequalities that hold for some number $m$ of variables but not $m+1$. Try it for two or three variables: square both sides and accounting for all the terms. What do you notice?

Comment: I understand it now. We've done mathematical induction, but I completely forgot about it. I guess it comes with experience. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @MarinKovač Don't worry, proofs take practice. If you stick with it things eventually become pretty natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, for ease of reading, lets us relabel. We want to prove the following: For $x_1, \ldots, x_n \geq 0$, we have that
$$
\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i.
$$
This is equivalent to stating that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 \leq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2.$$
Note that,
$$
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 + \underbrace{\sum_{i \neq j}x_ix_j}_{\geq 0},
$$
where the last term is greater or equal to zero by the assumption that $x_i \geq 0$ for all $i=1,\ldots,n$. Then this obsevation concludes the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Since both sides are not negative and $f(x)=x^2$ is increasing for $x\ge 0$, squaring both sides

$$\sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ...} \leqslant a + b + c + ...$$

$$\iff$$

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ... \leqslant (a + b + c + ...)^2=a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ...+2ab+...$$